# Redirect 301 a URL already created by a rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, url-rewriting

I'm creating SEO friendly URLs with rewrites in *.htaccess*.

Now I need to redirect (301) a couple of these rewrites, and have no idea how to do that.

**These lines:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /engines/index.php?engine_id=$1&urlTxt=$2 [L]
```

**Creates the following URL:**

```
 /engines/1009/malilla-35-hp-1938
```

**Now I need to redirect that URL to**

(Note the extra BRB):

```
/engines/1009/malilla-brb-35-hp-1938
```

Catch-22?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file located at `/engines/.htaccess`? Is this a one-off redirect? Or are you wanting to insert `-brb` in all URLs that follow a specific pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/engines` subdirectory (otherwise that rule won't match the stated URL).

There's no "Catch-22" here, in fact this looks like a simple redirect. The confusion may come about from a possible misunderstanding of the existing "rewrite rule"? That rule doesn't actually "create" the URL as such. The URL is already *created* when you make the initial request (eg. by clicking the link). That "rewrite rule" allows a URL of the form `/engines/<id>/<txt>` to "work" by internally rewriting the request to the underlying file `/engines/index.php?engine_id=<id>&urlTxt=<txt>` that actually handles the request.

You need to issue a redirect *before* the existing rewrite. So that it applies to the initial request and not the rewritten request.

To implement the stated redirect you should use mod_rewrite again (just as you are doing for the internal rewrite) and this rule needs to go *before* your existing rewrite (the order of the rules is important):

```
RewriteRule ^1009/malilla-35-hp-1938$ /engines/1009/malilla-brb-35-hp-1938 [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, use backreferences to avoid repetition:

```
RewriteRule ^(1009/malilla)(-35-hp-1938)$ /engines/$1-brb$2 [R=301,L]
```

Where `$1` and `$2` contain the text from the corresponding capturing subgroups in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

#### Summary

The resulting rules should then look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(1009/malilla)(-35-hp-1938)$ /engines/$1-brb$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /engines/index.php?engine_id=$1&urlTxt=$2 [L]
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /engines/index.php?engine_id=$1&urlTxt=$2 [L]
> ```

It looks like you could be more specific with the regex and avoid the need for the preceding *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) that perform the filesystem checks.

For example, assuming the `engine_id` is numeric only and the `urlTxt` cannot contain dots then the above can be reduced to a single directive, thus avoiding the filesystem checks (which is more efficient):

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /engines/index.php?engine_id=$1&urlTxt=$2 [L]
```

(I'm assuming there are no subdirectories that have numeric-only names.)

I would also be wary of allowing an optional trailing slash on the rewrite. This potentially permits *duplicate content*, since both URLs serve the same content. Your example URL does not include a trailing slash so it's possible this could simply be removed.

Comment: What great answer, much appreciated, thank you very much. Also a crystal clear explanation.